# what does SET NODE_ENV=dev do?

Tags: node.js, express

This sounds like a basic question but I couldn't find much information on this on google.

I am following a tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/test-a-node-restful-api-with-mocha-and-chai on testing node. There is a code in the package.json

```
"scripts":{
  "start": "SET NODE_ENV=dev && node server.js",
}
```

However, when I run it, I got the error.

```
WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'dev ' did not match any deployment config file names.
```

So my question is, what does SET NODE_ENV really do? How do you modify it when you want to put it to production?

EDITED on 10/10/2016
I found out from the documentation https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/ that the NODE_ENV will look for files in the config folder. so SET NODE_ENV = 'dev' looks for /config/dev.json. It's weird that the error occurs even though the dev.json exist. The app runs like normal so I am just wondering what the error means.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of obtuse way of setting an environmental variable.  Your code (or code in modules you require) might read it and make decisions based on how it's set.

I'm guessing from your error, that you're using `convict` or another config module that assumes the NODE_ENV will tell it if you're running the app in development mode or production mode, or testing mode, and load a configuration file that has a name matching e.g. `dev.json` or `dev.js` where specific stuff is set for that environment.

You could do the same thing afaik w/o the SET command, by just doing `NODE_ENV=dev node server.js` in the npm start script.

Answer (score 0):

SET NODE_ENV=dev Does exactly what it says. Establish an environment var called NODE_ENV to the "dev" value.
But what you're asking for is, probably, how this affect to my app ?

Well it depends on how your app is using it. Find somewhere ins source code where the checks for this value (Something like **process.env.NODE_ENV**, or similar) and  then will be possible to understand it

In your case it's used for a couple of things. Loading the correct config file, establish certain attribute for logging , get the mongo db URI ,etc

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space after 'dev' like:

```
scripts":{
  "start": "SET NODE_ENV=dev && node server.js",
}
```