# WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'dev ' did not match any deployment config file names(Windows)

Tags: node.js, windows-10

When I start node app I get the following warning. I am on windows 10.

`WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'dev ' did not match any deployment config file names.`

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=dev&& nodemon server.js",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
  }
```

dev.json file is already under config folder though but I am not sure why does it say 'dev ' instead of 'dev'

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you'll find a hint on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947895/what-does-set-node-env-dev-do?rq=1 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770052/warning-node-env-value-of-test-did-not-match-any-deployment-config-file-name?rq=1

Comment: What does your nodemon config look like?

Comment: @MarcoLüthy Thanks but I have already seen that before.

Comment: @Arcath I don't think it's nodemon config because I used to get this warning even before using nodemon.

Comment: I just changed the dev to devtest and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I changed from dev to devtest and it worked.